# How to login web application in phantom js as my requirement is to open a web app then take screenshot of different section?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I need to open a web app and then want to authenticate in that web app then will use phantomjs for pdf convertor.

Comment: And you try? please try it first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate the html, enter the username and password value, then submit. For that you have to check for the **classname** or **id** for **textbox**. 
Example: 
`page.evaluate(function(username, password) { 
$('#username').attr('value', username);$('#username').change();
$('#password').attr('value', password); $('#password').change();
$('.btn-login').click().submit();}, function() {  page.render('example.pdf');}, UserName, Password);`